# Custom Conditionals in Handlebars

Tags: coffeescript, handlebars.js

May be missing something simple, but how can I specify a conditional in Handlebars based on an operation on the object?

Looking to do something like

```
{{#hasDiscount this}}
  <tr>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td>{{formatPrice this.Discount}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/hasDiscount}}
```

With the helper along the lines of

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'hasDiscount', (cart) ->
  :runBlock: if cart.Discount > 0
```

Not sure how to tell it to run the block.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with it found an even simpler way.

```
{{#if hasDiscount}}
   <tr>
    <td>Discount</td>
    <td>{{formatPrice this.Discount}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/if}}
```

Because the cart was already the object in the template I could just set the helper like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'hasDiscount', ->
  true if @Discount > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The helper gets passed a `block` as the last argument. The `block` will be a function that you can run to get at the block's content, you can also `block.inverse()` to get at the `{{else}}` branch:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'hasDiscount', (cart, block) ->
  if cart.Discount > 0
    block()
  else
    block.inverse()
```

The [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals) doesn't really spell this out so you have to make some guesses and try a few things based on the examples.